# Fluid condition with ContainsViewHelper

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, fluid, viewhelper

i use this condition in my fluid template:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.image.className} == 'lightbox'">
                <f:then>
                    ....do something
                </f:then>

        <f:else>
          <f:if condition="{settings.image.className} !== 'lightbox'">
                <f:then>
                 ....do something else
                </f:then>
         </f:if>
         </f:else>
```

It works fine but if $settings.image.className" is something like "lightbox container" instead of just "lightbox" it does not work of course. 
Unfortunately i do not know how write a condtion that checks if $settings.image.className contains "lightbox" or not.

The only instructions i found are here:
[ViewHelper Reference](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/String/ContainsViewHelper.html) .However i do not know how to apply that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this to the top of the partial/content Element

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

and change the logic like this

```
<v:condition.string.contains haystack="{settings.image.className}" needle="lightbox">
   <f:then>
        ....do something
   </f:then>
   <f:else>
        ....do something else
   </f:else>
</v:condition.string.contains>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. There was no need add a namespace, it was already defined this way: {namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}.
Also the closing tag should be </v:condition.string.contains>.

Comment: Oh i'll correct that if someone has the same issue ;)

Comment: How do i check if the haystack contains needle "lightbox" or needle "fancybox"?

Comment: source code reference of the viewhelper: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/Condition/String/ContainsViewHelper.php#L41

Comment: The needle has to be a string since it only checks for a string position. You have to check twice, basically, you copy the content of my answer a second time into the "else" branch.

Or you use the new syntax for TYPO3 8 `<f:else if="{ ... inline version of v:condition.string.contains ... }"> ....do something else </f:else>`

Comment: Cheers i was looking for the TYPO3 8 syntax.